# Center SVG image in background

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm having a problem centering a SVG image in the background.

Here is the CCS:

```css
.cs-title {
  display: block;
  background: url("../logo.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 440px;  
  background-position:left center;
  float: center;
}
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Sam's comments. Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944354/svg-background-image-position-is-always-centered-in-internet-explorer-despite-b).

Comment: Without details of the SVG itself we can't offer much advice. If the logo isn't itself centered inside the SVG you are going to have trouble.

Comment: You also be aware that there is no such property/value as `float:center`

Answer (score 0):

For a logo, I would place the svg on the page rather than as a background image. Also, without more information, I would guess that the issue is with the svg itself. Have you got the `viewbox` propety set to the svg dimensions in the svg code, as well as height and width set to 100%?