# background position for internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I currently have a background image with `background-position: center bottom;` also tried `background-position-x: center; background-position-y: bottom` but for internet explorer it does not work. THe image is sticking to the top. Is there a solution to set the background image position to the bottom that will work for all browsers?

I forgot to mention I am using SVG as the background image.

Comment: Is it really `position: bottom;`?

Comment: I meant background position but that doesnt change the problem I have

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some code @henhen? This should work but the parent element may be shorter than you think or the background properties may be being overwritten.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svg background image position is always centered in internet explorer, despite background-position: left center;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944354/svg-background-image-position-is-always-centered-in-internet-explorer-despite-b)

Answer (score 0):

The background-position css property works as expected in Internet Explorer even if you are using an svg as the background image.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/aa.svg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: It must be dont in regular Internet Exploter 9-11 not IE Edge with emulation. I am also using SVG as background

Comment: Still works with an svg as the background image, in IE - not Edge with emulation - but not all svgs are created equal and you haven't posted your code so there may be additional issues.