# How to ensure that an SVG path (design) remains in the dead center, no matter what happens to the vewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native, svg

I have a project that basically works in 2 layers. The layer at the bottom has a large SVG object with a ton of different paths. The layer on top is a small SVG object that I want to keep perfectly centered.
The bottom layer has a CSS position of absolute and the top one is fixed. The top SVG "kindof" stays centered, but if I change the zoom on the Safari browser for example, then the centered effect is lost in some scenarios.
**Are there life cycle methods in web design? Can I call a method whenever ANY change occurs to the viewport, that could allow me to reposition the top layer SVG design dynamically, and for it to remain perfectly centered no matter what?**

*PS: I'm looking to eventually move this project onto React-Native (which I know nothing about), Are web design rules even relevant if you're looking to migrate to a mobile based platform?
Apologies for the lack of code, Thank You for reading!*

Answer (score 0):

Put this two lines in style.css In your specified div class.

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

and then try to run it, you will be able to see that .svg aligned in the center.

or
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944354/svg-background-image-position-is-always-centered-in-internet-explorer-despite-b) if mine dose not work

Comment: Hi, I'm still not having any luck with this. If I place let's say a simple circle SVG and try to center it, and go on Safari (on mobile) the circle doesn't stay centered as I zoom and pan around.  Thanks for the response tho!

Comment: hey, there try out this [link](https://css-tricks.com/unfortunately-clip-path-path-is-still-a-no-go/) as the code above works for me in chrome @SteveM.